# Are UUID's, and the most basic level, just a string of unique characters?

Tags: ios, uuid, nsuuid

I am currently learning about UUID in iOS, and of course I'm trying to make sense of them.  From what I can gather, when you call NSUUID(), it returns a 128 bit string that is completely unique (though I'm not currently interested in how it can ensure a completely unique string, I figure it takes into account the date, time, and device identity).  To make use of this string, you can append it to the end of the Document Directory (which I believe is unique to each application) to ensure a unique file path that can be used to access files later.  Is this a correct understanding of the concept?

Comment: I don't think it's completely unique, fyi

Comment: They are unique in as far as it's very very unlikely to ever generate two random numbers (or strings) of that length independently.

Comment: *In other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%.* You can assume them to be unique. Dont take any other mesasures to unify them even more — it just doesnt worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

[Globally Unique Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) are 128-bit binary strings.

Microsoft COM uses them to prevent "name collisions" between components *without* needing some "central naming authority" (like we have for DNS names, IP addresses, broadcast frequencies, etc etc).

GUIDs are *likely* to be unique ... but it's not *guaranteed*.

Here is a good article explaining more:

- http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/

And yes, your understanding of iOS NSUUIDs is exactly right:

- http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/
- http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/

Comment: These are great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Universally unique identifier. Version 4 is almost guaranteed to be unique but not completely. Wikipedia states the following:

"Out of a total of 128 bits, two bits indicate an RFC 4122 ("Leach-Salz") UUID and four bits the version (0100 indicating "randomly generated"), so randomly generated UUIDs have 122 random bits. The chance of two such UUIDs having the same value can be calculated using probability theory (birthday paradox). Using the approximation"

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29